# Как сделать таблицу рекордов в игре на Javascript с использованием localstorage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

В общем, суть в следующем. В начале игры заполняются данные формы, типа Имя, Фамилия, и отправляются в localstorage. После окончания игры эти данные должны отобразиться в таблице. При следующем запуске игры опять вводятся данные, если таких еще не было в хранилище, то они туда добавляются. И потом опять они отображаются в таблице по окончании игры. Таблица в общем на 10 результатов должна быть. Подскажите алгоритм, как это все можно реализовать?

Comment: вы на самом деле сами в свободной форме описали весь алгоритм

Comment: Я не могу разобраться, как в localstorage добавлять постоянно новые данные, не перезаписывая старые?

Comment: @ОлегИщук, храните данные формы в объекте, и `let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name') || {}); ... localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(obj));`, где вместо `...` ваш код оперирующий данными.

Comment: При таком способе, когда в игру будет добавляться новый пользователь, то данные в хранилище будут перезаписываться? Я имею ввиду, ключ name?